# How can I make a rest compatible multiselect list with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rest

I want to have a list like in this example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior
But I wan't it so the User can click and select and unselect Items just by clicking on them, and then be able to get the ids of the selected items through javascript.
I also would like to be able to fill it by using an ajax rest request at startup and after every click on a button labeled "Update", so the List can update itself without reloading the page.
Basicly I want an interface that takes a list of tasks through the rest api and displays them in a multiselect list.
The User then selects which tasks have been done and clicks update, at which point a rest request updates the servers list of tasks (this part is no problem) and reloads all the remaining tasks into the list without refershing the page.

Comment: But what is the question ..?

Comment: fixed it, its a question now